# What might I do differently to avoid the following error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDDPartition?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I have created a custom Docker Image for Spark 2.4.1. My docker-compose spins up spark-master, spark-worker-1 and spark-worker-2 containers. Everything works perfectly including my pyspark script, until I try to execute the following function within the script:

```
def infer_topic_schema_json(schema_topic, schema_inference_sample_size):
    df_json = (spark.read.format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker:29092")
            .option("subscribe", schema_topic)
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
            .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", schema_inference_sample_size)
            .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
            .load()
            .withColumn("value", F.expr("string(value)"))
            .select("value"))
    df_read = spark.read.json(df_json.rdd.map(lambda x: x.value), multiLine=True)
    return df_read.schema.json()
```

I end up getting the error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDDPartition

The error occurs here specifically:

```
df_read = spark.read.json(df_json.rdd.map(lambda x: x.value), multiLine=True)
```

I am using Spark version 2.4.1, and the confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:7.0.0 image for Kafka.

I am attempting to trigger the spark job using the following command:

> docker exec -it my-container's-id spark-submit --packages
> 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.1'
> /app/spark_processor.py

I have ensured I am using the correct package within the --packages option. The only solution I have found on the internet suggested ensuring that the correct package was being used, and I have done that.

I have been stuck with this problem for days now. Would appreciate any help you could provide.

Comment: `--packages 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.1'`  << try using this in your docker command. Generally this type of error indicates either java or scala version mismatch. Spark 2.4.1 is compiled using Scala 2.12. So the `_2.12` in the package represents the scala version used to compile that package.

Comment: Heyy, I've already tried that as well. It doesn't work either.

Comment: If I use that version, I get "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated"

Comment: This is a better error than the class not found error. So congratulations, you have made some progress.